# Hidden main tabs after adding the script to the page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I was added the JS-script to the library page and the main tabs were closed, how to restore the tab with the added script.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a content editor web part with this JavaScript code:

```
 setTimeout(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2");
    if(elem != null) {
        var dummyevent = new Array();
        dummyevent["target"] = elem;
        dummyevent["srcElement"] = elem;
        WpClick(dummyevent);
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I'm a testing :)